# Complete unbounded interval

Tags: real-analysis

Why is $[1,\infty)$ complete?

I know that every Cauchy sequence should converge for the space to be complete, but I cannot see it.
Taking a sequence in this space then $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists  n>0$ s.t. if m>n then $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$

A sequence in this space converges iff $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists  n>0$ s.t. if m>n then $d(x_m,l)<\epsilon$

Comment: Do you know why $\Bbb R$ is complete in the usual metric?

Comment: @Brian I thought it was b/c every point in R has a sequence that converges at that point?

Comment: No, that really has nothing to do with it. Completeness means that every Cauchy sequence converges, so $\Bbb R$ is complete because we can prove that every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$ converges. If you’re allowed to use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete, you can prove that $[1,\infty)$ is complete by showing that every Cauchy sequence in $[1,\infty)$ is Cauchy in $\Bbb R$ and then showing that its limit must actually be in $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: A way of testing your understanding is this: If your remove any single point from $[1,\infty)$, the result will no longer be complete.

Comment: Klara: Generalizing this, here is a good exercise:  If $X$ is a complete metric space, and $A\subseteq X$ is given the same metric restricted to $A$, then $A$ is complete if and only if $A$ is closed in $X$.  For one direction, you need only mimic Henno's answer.  For the other direction, I'd suggest first completing the exercise in vadim123's comment as a warmup.

Answer (score 1):

If we have a Cauchy sequence in $A = [1,\infty)$, so $(x_n)$ (all in $A$) with the property that $\forall \epsilon>0: \exists k: \forall m,m \ge k: d(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon$, where $d$ denotes the Euclidean metric, then this sequence is also a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ (using the same metric $d$ of course): we use nothing about points being in $A$ or not: the property is intrinsic to the sequence and the used metric.

But as $\mathbb{R}$ is complete there is some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_n \to x$ as $n \to \infty$.

If $x \notin A$, then there is some ball $B(x,r), r>0$ that misses $A$, because $A$ is a closed set. But then there can be no points of $A$ within distance $r$ of $x$, and this contradicts $x_n \to x$. So $x \in A$. But now $x_n \to x$ *in $A$* (because the limit is in $A$ and we use the same distance). So we have shown that all Cauchy sequences in $A$ converge to a point in $A$, just using that the ambient space ($\mathbb{R}$ in our case) is complete and the subspace $A$ is closed. It *is* essential we are using the same metric on both.